# Как получить номер страницы с адреса сайта для пагинации

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, pagination

Как получить номер страницы с адреса сайта? Например отсюда надо получить - 2(номер страницы может быть любой, адрес страницы также может быть любымб сохраняется только #page-номер_страницы) 
https://somesite-address/inner-page#page-2

Comment: это адрес страницы, на которой выполняется js ? `window.location.hash.toString().split('-').pop()`

Comment: Нет это просто пример

Comment: если скрипт должен получить адрес той страницы, на которой выполняется, то написал в первом комментарии. если это просто строка, str.split('-').pop()

Comment: Спасибо, помогло)